# Laplace equation in parabolic coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I'm stuck on a seemingly simple 2D electrostatics problem which doesn't allow for straightforward solution by separation of variables:

A parabolic interface, with its axis parallel to the $x$ axis, separates two regions of different conductivity, with a uniform electric field at infinity aligned with the $x$-axis.

To begin Laplace's equation is written in parabolic coordinates, where $x=\frac{c(u^2-v^2)}{2}$ and $y=cuv$ as

$\nabla^{2} \phi(u,v)=\frac{1}{c^2(u^2+v^2)}\left(\phi_{uu}+\phi_{vv}\right)=0$

Using separation of variables ($\phi(u,v)=U(u)V(v)$) gives solutions of the form

(1): $\phi(u,v)=(A_{0}u+B_{0})(C_{0}v+D_{0})+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(A_{n}e^{knu}+B_{n}e^{-knu})(C_{n}\textrm{cos}(knv)+D_{n}\textrm{sin}(knv))$.

At infinity where the electric field constant, the potential must be $\phi=-E_{0}x=-E_{0}\frac{c(u^2-v^2)}{2}$. This form is required as the axis of the parabola must be parallel with the direction of the imposed field.

Is there another method for solving this problem, or does this specific problem not admit an analytical solution?

Comment: If you swap x and y then it looks like the bilinear part of phi will capture the dependence phi=const*x